# Add and remove cross datas with highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts

UPDATE -> Here is the jsfiffle http://jsfiddle.net/Lx3Xq/

my brain is kind of freezing here.
I try to add and remove different kind of data from my highcharts object. I know the technique but right here, i don't know how to cross my datas.
So here is my php file that brings my datas (with json)

```
$categories = array(
    'Health' => [380,442,472],
    'Mana' => [250,215,220],
    'Attack Damage' => [50,55,47],
    'Armor' => [15,18.5,22],
    'Attack Speed' => [0.67,0.63,0.64],
    'Magic Resist' => [30,30,30],
    'Movement Speed' => [330,330,335]
);
$champions = array('CharacterName1','CharacterName2','CharacterName3');
$graph_data = array('categories'=>$categories, 'champions'=>$champions);

echo json_encode($graph_data);
exit;
```

I create then my chart like this

```
$.each(data.categories, function(key, value){                       
    var series = {};
    series.name = key;
    series.data = value;                        
    options.series.push(series);    
})

$.each(data.champions, function(key, value){                        
    var categories = [];
    options.xAxis.categories.push(value);
})

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

No problems i have an x axis with my characters name and the values of series named "Health", "Mana" etc... in a column chart.
Thing is, i want to add or remove some of my characters data via checkboxes. I create the checkboxes

```
var mesRadio = document.getElementById('monForm');
var mesCheksBoxes = '';    
for (var i = 0; i < data.champions.length; i++) {                       
    mesCheksBoxes += '<label>'+data.champions[i]+'<input type="checkbox" class="choice" name="choice-'+i+'" value="'+data.champions[i]+'"></label>';
};                  
mesRadio.innerHTML = mesCheksBoxes;
```

This is were i'm freezing. I would like to send the data and name of my series (array categories) bound by my characters names (array champions). But i don't know wich method will be the right one.
If someone have some idea and some lead i can follow, that will be great.
Thanks

Comment: Probably your line series.data = value;      attach string not array. In other words you achieve something like series.data = "[380,442,472]".

Comment: however my chart take the good datas. My character 1 receive 380 in mana, my character 2 442 in mana etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add remove them use:

- [`chart.addSeries(series_object)`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries)
- [`chart.series[index_of_series_to_remove].remove()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.remove) - note if you remove series with index=0, then series with index=1 will take it's place. Instead of using indexes, you can add to each series `id` and then use `chart.get(id)`, to get series to remove.

Or maybe you just want to hide series from a chart? Then simple use:

- [`chart.series[index].hide()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.hide)
- [`chart.series[index].show()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.show)

Second solution is much easier.

Note: To hide/show/add/remove series you need to add event to each of checkboxes and in callback update chart.

Comment: Ho yes, your id idea is good, i'm trying this. My whole problem was not how to hide/remove/add series, but how to cross datas of my 2 arrays in order to hide/show or remove/add datas of my array 1 (categories) based on the index of my array 2 (champions). I'm digging, thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Maybe instead of `data.champions[i]` in value, use simple index? Then using that index you can hide/show specific index. To be honest, if you could create jsFiddle demo with some static data (as an example) it would be great help :)

Comment: Yes here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/Lx3Xq/ 
I keep in comments my json call. I normally construct my checkboxes in my js.

Comment: Thanks, that demo is really helpful. Unfortunately, you can't hide full category in Highcharts (like Character 2) - onle series like in legend. You can however implement something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lx3Xq/1/ - it's not a perfect solution, but a good starting point. Another solution would be to use `setExtremes()` but unfortunatetly, with `setExtremes()` solution you can hide only left/right most characters.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Unforunatelly, i try another way to arrange my datas by making this : http://jsfiddle.net/Leminence/jZmYJ/
I'm using the highchats API in order to add/remove datas. It seems great so far, i'm digging this solution. Though, your script can be helpfull for other update i want to do in this project. Thanks again.
PS : I think you're right, we can't handle safe solutions with my first method.